# Modifying cells in pandas df does not succeed

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to modify cells in existing df -- if I find string with no alpha characters (e.g such as "*" ) I set it to "0.0" string and when all cells are processed I try to convert a column numeric type.
But setting "0.0" for some reason does not reflect in resulting df

```
for i, col in enumerate(cols):
    for ii in range(0, df.shape[0]):
        row = df.iloc[ii]
        value = row[col]

        if isinstance(value, str):
            if not( utils.representsInt(value) or utils.representsFloat(value) ) and re.search('[a-zA-Z]', x) is None:
                df.iat[ii, i] = "0.0"

     df[col] = df[col].astype(np.float_)
    #df[col] = df[col].to_numeric() #this throws error that Series does not have to_numeric()
```

I get error

```
could not convert string to float: 'cat'
```

And when I print df I see that values were not changed.
What could be the issue?

Thanks!

df

```
f289,f290,f291,f292,f293,f294,f295,f296,f297,f298,f299,f300,f301,f302,f303,f304,f305,f306,f307,f308,f309,f310
01M015,P.S. 015 Roberto Clemente,Elementary,1.0,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*
01M019,P.S. 019 Asher Levy,Elementary,1.0,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*
01M020,P.S. 020 Anna Silver,Elementary,1.0,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*
01M034,P.S. 034 Franklin D. Roosevelt,K-8,1.0,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,14
01M063,The STAR Academy - P.S.63,Elementary,1.0,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,6
01M064,P.S. 064 Robert Simon,Elementary,1.0,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*
01M110,P.S. 110 Florence Nightingale,Elementary,1.0,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*
01M134,P.S. 134 Henrietta Szold,Elementary,1.0,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*
01M137,P.S. 137 John L. Bernstein,Elementary,1.0,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*
01M140,P.S. 140 Nathan Straus,K-8,1.0,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*
01M142,P.S. 142 Amalia Castro,Elementary,1.0,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*
01M184,P.S. 184m Shuang Wen,K-8,1.0,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*
01M188,P.S. 188 The Island School,K-8,1.0,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,10
```

So, in this case, I expect this `df` to have "0.0" instead of "*" and these cols to have numeric datatype e.g `float` after conversion

Comment: quite a nested for loop, can you post your sample data so we can help with your query? as for why it doesn't work is because 1. you have strings in your float 2. your calling `.to_numeric` wrong try `pd.to_numeric(df[col],errors='coerce')`

Comment: what about `df.applymap(lambda x: 0.0 if isinstance(x, str) and (not( utils.representsInt(x) or utils.representsFloat(x))) else x)))`

Comment: @splash58 updated post

Comment: @Datanovice updated post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change condition for returning 0.0, I set for test `x=="*"`

```
df.iloc[:,3:] = df.iloc[:,3:].applymap(lambda x: 0.0 if x=="*" else x)

      f289                            f290        f291  ...  f308  f309  f310
0   01M015       P.S. 015 Roberto Clemente  Elementary  ...   0.0   0.0     0
1   01M019             P.S. 019 Asher Levy  Elementary  ...   0.0   0.0     0
2   01M020            P.S. 020 Anna Silver  Elementary  ...   0.0   0.0     0
3   01M034  P.S. 034 Franklin D. Roosevelt         K-8  ...   0.0   0.0    14
4   01M063       The STAR Academy - P.S.63  Elementary  ...   0.0   0.0     6
5   01M064           P.S. 064 Robert Simon  Elementary  ...   0.0   0.0     0
6   01M110   P.S. 110 Florence Nightingale  Elementary  ...   0.0   0.0     0
7   01M134        P.S. 134 Henrietta Szold  Elementary  ...   0.0   0.0     0
8   01M137      P.S. 137 John L. Bernstein  Elementary  ...   0.0   0.0     0
9   01M140          P.S. 140 Nathan Straus         K-8  ...   0.0   0.0     0
10  01M142          P.S. 142 Amalia Castro  Elementary  ...   0.0   0.0     0
11  01M184            P.S. 184m Shuang Wen         K-8  ...   0.0   0.0     0
12  01M188      P.S. 188 The Island School         K-8  ...   0.0   0.0    10
```

**Update**

define function

```
def f(value) :
   if isinstance(value, str):
      if not(utils.representsInt(value) or utils.representsFloat(value) ) and re.search('[a-zA-Z]', x) is None:
      return 0.0
   return float(value)
```

Apply it to each cell

```
df = df.applymap(f)
```

Comment: this should be automated without harcoding. dataframe is just an example.. I have tens of thousands of different tables that needs this processing and "*" can be replaced by any other non-alpha characters, as well as columns that needs processing can be arbitrary located

Comment: that is why I use provided functions

Comment: Ok. you can apply not to slice but to all frame df.apply. and not test lambda but real function